# How to convert a large tokenized dfm to matrix in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, tokenize, text-mining

I have a large tokenized dfm of the dimension 2656242 x 630566. I want to convert this to a matrix but any kind of operation on this gives me the following error

***Error in asMethod(object) :
Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105***

My code till now is as below:

```
Booker_PreSale = Samp2 %>% filter(Booking_Status=="Booker" & Pre_Post_Sale=="Pre-Sale")
Non_Booker_PreSale = Samp2 %>% filter(Booking_Status=="Non-Booker" & Pre_Post_Sale=="Pre-Sale")
data = rbind(Booker_PreSale,Non_Booker_PreSale)
data = data[,c(5,2)]
data = na.omit(data)
data$Booking_Status = as.factor(data$Booking_Status)
data$TextLength = nchar(as.character(data$comments))
    
library(caret)
set.seed(32984)
indexes = createDataPartition(data$Booking_Status,times = 1,
                              p=0.7,list = FALSE)

train = data[indexes,]
test = data[-indexes,]

library(quanteda)

train_tokens = tokens(as.character(train$comments), what = "word", 
                      remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
                      remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE)

train_tokens = tokens_tolower(train_tokens)
train_tokens = tokens_select(train_tokens, stopwords(), 
                              selection = "remove")

train_tokens = tokens_wordstem(train_tokens, language = "english")

train_tokens_dfm = dfm(train_tokens, tolower = FALSE)
train_tokens_matrix = as.matrix(train_tokens_dfm[,c(1:500)])
```

I am unable to proceed any further from this. Need some help with a way around this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the error occur after the `dfm()` line, or after the `as.matrix()` line? Probably the latter. You are trying to to create a dense matrix with 1.6 trillion cells! Consider using the methods in **quanteda.textmodels** on the dfm directly - they do not require conversion to a dense matrix. Also you should trim the dfm using frequency-based selection - no single corpus should have 630,566 types.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your dfm is simply to large. Therefore, first ask yourself whether you really need to convert your dfm object to a matrix. If you want to fit a model (e.g., a topic model) that takes your tokenized documents as input, you most likely do not need to convert the dfm object to a matrix!

If you do not explicitly need a matrix, I would recommend to first convert your dfm object to a non-quanteda format; this can be achieved using

`non_dfm <- quanteda::convert(train_tokens_dfm)`.

You can then extract the dfm content as a list of lists using `dfm_list<-non_dfm$vocab`. Each list element is associated with a document and contains two rows: the first row gives the index of the token, and the second row is the number of occurrences of this token in the document. You thus have exactly the same information that is contained in a document feature matrix.

Comment: Thanks i tried this but getting the following error. Any way around this?

**_Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147_**

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know how to proceed. However, what surprises me is that you were able to generate the dfm object in the first place, since this is the most expensive part computationally. Have you tried restarting R and executing your script again?

Comment: Tried running it again, it runs fine. Even if i do not convert this into a matrix I need to cbind the Booking_Status column to be able to create my model, since my ultimate aim is to be able to classify a text as for a 'booker' or 'non-booker'. However, any ops with this dfm, including bind is throwing this error,

**_Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105_**

Comment: I managed to convert this into a non-dfm, next i want to use the following code.

`train_tokens_df = cbind(Booking_Status = train$Booking_Status, as.matrix(non_dfm))`

How can i convert the non-dfm into a matrix to bind?